# Looping a list and adjusting it

Tags: asp.net, .net, foreach

I want to say that my code works correctly but i don't know why it is working like that. So to make it clear, here is my code:

```
List<NewsFlash> newsfl = tsm.getNewsFlashes();

foreach (NewsFlash item in newsfl)
{
    item.smartform.dtDate = item.smartform.dtDate.ToShortDateString();
}

//Get all the newsFlash items and bind to the repeater
rptNewsFlash.DataSource = newsfl;
rptNewsFlash.DataBind();
```

Like you can see, I am looping the list `newsfl` and I am editing `item.smartform.dtDate`. What is weird for me is, when I edit `item.smartform.dtDate`, then the property `dtDate` in the list `newsfl` is also changed. This is what I want, but it is kind of weird I think, because `item` within the foreach loop has nothing to do with the list `newsfl`?

Hope you understand my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `item` in the `foreach` is just a reference to the item at a specific index within `newsfl` - so when your loop is done, you've updated all the `item`'s in the list, and those items hang onto those changes. This makes sense because each item is not a copy of the original, it *is* the original.

So, imagine `item` and `newsfl[n]` as two doors to the same room, you end up in the same place - and it doesn't matter which door I arrive through, if I start moving furniture around, it is also moved for anyone who comes in through either door.

On another note, if this *didn't* happen, then what would you expect to happen? Since you make changes to `item`, surely you *want* to keep them?

Comment: I was testing this. I had in mind to create another list and add all the items in that newly created list in the loop. But I didn't know this functionality, so it made it easier now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the line `foreach (NewsFlash item in newsfl)` you take a reference, called `item`, to each of the entries in `newsfl`. This doesn't create a copy of the item, just a reference to the item in the list.

That way if you update a value on `item`, the entry in `newfl` will also be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't it be changed? The object "item" in your foreach loop is exactly the same object as the one in your "newsfl" list. Actually the object "item" only points to the correct object in the list.